# Strange learning curve

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am training a CNN to localize points on image and i obtain an oscillating validation curve and obtain 90% accuracy on the training score and 20% in the test score…Why?

I tried regularization, dropout, earlystopping and modelcheckpoint with keras and none of this solutions worked

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of factors that affect this process. As you already mentioned some of the things you have tried. You could try changing the way you initialize the weights. The other factors could be the learning rate, regularization factor, the type of optimizer you are using.

Try using different combinations of learning rate and regularization and plot the loss function. Observing the loss function could be really helpful.

At the end of the day, mostly the results are empirical and a lot depends on your dataset and how you have divided it. Make sure you have chosen the training set at random and not the initial or the final 70% of the data. Also, I would recommend having a validation set (I am not if that is what you mean by checkpoints).

I have experienced what you are saying, it could be because of a silly mistake in your code or could be because of the way you divided your database. Unfortunately, there is not a specific answer to this question.

Comment: Thank you for these advices. I also tried to reduce layers/units, it didn't help. And i randomly shuffled the dataset and use a validation set for the validation score. I will try to optimize with learning rate